# Is it true that football World cup trophy is always changed, when a country wins it 3 times?

Tags: football, world-cup

When in 1970 Brazil wins Jules Rimet Trophy for the third time, then for the next world cup in 1974 the trophy is new - so called FIFA World Cup Trophy. Since then Germany has won the cup 3 times, the last in 2014. Should we expect a new World Cup trophy or this is just a rumour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is untrue. Quoting from [FIFA's page about the trophy](http://www.fifa.com/about-fifa/marketing/brand/trophy.html):

> The original FIFA World Cup Trophy cannot be won outright anymore, as the new regulations state that it shall remain in FIFA's possession.

Comment: If anyone can find the actual regulations, please (propose an) edit to include the appropriate link and wording.

Comment: Ok, so that is untrue now, but was true before. Just the regulation are changed now and Germany cannot take the title forever.